# Leaked GCP API Keys

Tags: android-security

We have followed the google instructions on how to prevent this error from coming up in Play Store. i.e. our keys are specified in the gradle local.properties file.  We built and are referencing the keys from our app as follows:-

```
Places.initialize(context, BuildConfig.keyname);
```

The error still comes up in Google Play Console.  How do we prevent this from happening?